# Pymodbus serial forwarder with multiple slaves

Tags: pymodbus

I am using `Pymodbus` serial forwarder [example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/remote_server_context.html) which works fine for one serial device. I want to be able to poll more than one device in the bus.
As discussed [here](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/463) it seems (and my tests confirm) that the `ModbusServerContext` does not pass down unit id.
Is there any workaround to enable polling of more than one device (say unit ids 1 & 2) in the serial forwarder example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the above should be:

```
store = {
    1: RemoteSlaveContext(client, unit=1),
    2: RemoteSlaveContext(client, unit=2)}
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=False)
```

Since I want to forward all normal addresses, I am doing this:

```
  store = {unit_number: RemoteSlaveContext(client, unit=unit_number) 
           for unit_number in range(1, 248)}
  context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: In fact this was also discussed [here](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/569), but your solution seems much better

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, one could use the following:

```
store = {0x1:RemoteSlaveContext(client),0x2:RemoteSlaveContext(client)}
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=False)
```

With this setup, unit ids are passed down.
But till now there is a bug and the response might originate from either (1 or 2) serial unit ids.